# setTimeout trigger on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to delay a timeout effect, currently the effect starts when the page is loaded, I want it to start when I scroll to a certain div
[Here is how it currently is](https://jsfiddle.net/0fmfgL3u/1/)

I did some searching and found a library called waypoint that allows to trigger events based on waypoints using the code below but no luck.I also tried setting the display to none and change it once the css animation was triggered but when it appeared on the page the progress bars were already in place.

```
 var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is the JSFiddle that I could come up with. 
https://jsfiddle.net/md0m60cb/6/

Have a look at the CSS, i changed some ID's into classes there. With that, I did the following in the Javascript:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#startAnimation').waypoint(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#progress-html').addClass('progress-html-class');
                }, 2800);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#progress-css').addClass('progress-css-class');
                }, 3500);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#progress-javascript').addClass('progress-javascript-class');
                }, 4200);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#progress-php').addClass('progress-php-class');
                }, 4900);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#progress-angular').addClass('progress-angular-class');
                }, 5600);
            });
        });
```

So, what does it do? Using JQuery, I assigned a waypoint to the row that holds the animations (with the id `#startAnimation`). As soon as it reaches that waypoint, I set timeouts with the varying delays that add the necessary css classes, which in turn trigger the animation.

I hope I could clarify what I did here. If you have questions, just reply.

Comment: Wow thanks very much! Took awhile to figure it out, you basically added the class to the elements once the waypoint was reached then the css now had something to work with and applied the rules, it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

using javasript function `onscroll()`. set the the `onscroll` function to the `div` tag and set animation using `setTimeOut()` and `clearTimeOut()`.
the event function `onscroll()` will trigger the animation until it reaches the target `div` tag it stops.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the animation was done using css and not timeout as I originally thought, so I just had to try and manipulate css rules while scrolling